# How to display "NO RESULT" -- ANDROID

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

how can I make it display "no result found". here's the code..

```
final BinderActorData bindingData = new BinderActorData(this,
                actorDataCollection);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
// Adding items to listview
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

list.setAdapter(bindingData);

/**
* Enabling Search Filter
* */
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    bindingData.getFilter().filter(cs);
    list.setAdapter(bindingData);
}
```

Then onClick I am using following code:

```
// Click event for single list row
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(BrowseActors.this, ViewActor.class);
int t = position;
// parameters
i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position + 1));

 /*
  * selected item parameters
 */

  i.putExtra("name",
                actorDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_NAME));
  i.putExtra("icon",
                actorDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON));
  i.putExtra("career",
                actorDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_CAREER));

        // start the sample activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

here actorDataCollection is I am populating from external XML, based on Tags.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> actorDataCollection;
```

This is my custom BaseAdapter:

```
public class BinderActorData extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
static final String KEY_TAG = "ActorData"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ICON = "icon";
static final String KEY_CAREER = "career";

LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<HashMap<String, String>> actorDataCollection;
private List<HashMap<String, String>> filteredData;
ViewHolder holder;
private Context context;

public BinderActorData(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public BinderActorData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public BinderActorData(Activity act, List<HashMap<String, String>> map) {

    this.actorDataCollection = map;
    this.filteredData = map;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return filteredData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // type
        holder.actorImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb
                                                                            // image
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }


    // Get data from filtered Data
    holder.name.setText(filteredData.get(position).get(KEY_NAME));
    // Setting Thumbnail image
    String imageUri = filteredData.get(position).get(KEY_ICON);

    AssetActivity a = new AssetActivity();
    context = vi.getContext();
    Drawable image = a.getImage(imageUri, context);
    holder.actorImage.setImageDrawable(image);

    return vi;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    ImageView actorImage;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            // If there's nothing to filter on, return the original data for
            // your list
            if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                results.values = actorDataCollection;
                results.count = actorDataCollection.size();
            } else {
                List<HashMap<String, String>> filterResultsData = new      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < actorDataCollection.size(); i++) {
                    if (actorDataCollection.get(i).get(KEY_NAME)
                            .toLowerCase().toString()
                            .indexOf(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                        filterResultsData.add(actorDataCollection.get(i));
                    }
                }

                results.values = filterResultsData;
                results.count = filterResultsData.size();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence,
                FilterResults filterResults) {
            filteredData = (List<HashMap<String, String>>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example and not your whole project and also provide some information on the context, where do you want "no result" and why do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` has a [`setEmptyView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) method.

Though there are many ways of going about getting a `View` to pass in as the empty View, I generally put a `TextView` in the XML layout containing my `ListView`, and set it like so:

```
View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.my_empty_view);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

Comment: It looks like you could just call `Toast.makeText()` at the end of your `performFiltering()` method, assuming that's when you wanted to show the Toast. The only catch is that you need to make sure you have a valid `Context`, since you only store a `Context` reference in one of your constructors.